# What's API call method of statistics?

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I want to provide LinkedIn statistics, but i can not see stats URI.

So, what is [Socialbakers LinkedIn Statistics](http://www.socialbakers.com/linkedin-statistics) API using?
Thanks.

Comment: your name is john and your english is bad?:)

Comment: Statistics about your own network on LinkedIn, or stats about the LinkedIn site in general (as the Socialbakers link suggests)?

Comment: Statistics about LinkedIn general site (as like Socialbakers Stats)

Answer (score 0):

They aren't using a **public** (*that's if they are even using anything from LinkedIn*) LinkedIn API.

They also have statistics for Twitter and twitter doesn't offer those statistics in their API. I don't know where they get their stats from, but its not from the API everyone has access to.

**Edit** : *I used **public** because they might be using a private API that LinkedIn offers them*